# How do you load an SQLite3 database file into using PyQt6.QSQL?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt6, qsqldatabase

I'm playing around with PyQt6 and QSQL.

The code down here was meant to load a sqlite3 database into a QTableView

But instead, it will load only the headers of a table into the table view.

What do I have to correct in order to display the data along with the headers?

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi


def createConnection() -> bool:
    con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')

    con.setDatabaseName('data\\data.sqlite3')

    print(con.database())
    if not con.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            'QTableView Example - Error!',
            'Database Error: %s' % con.lastError().databaseText(),
        )
        return False
    return True


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi('resources\\forms\\tabletutorial.ui', self)
        # Set the window title
        self.setWindowTitle('QTable Example')

        # Create the model
        model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        # Set the table to display

        model.setTable('MOCK_STAFF_DATA')
        # model.setTable('MOCK_STUDENT_DATA')
        # Set the data model for table widget
        self.tableView.setModel(model)

        # Adjust column widths to their content
        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(1)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    widget.setFixedHeight(1000)
    widget.setFixedWidth(1500)

    widget.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())

    except:
        print('Exiting')


run()
```

Comment: As explained [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html#details): "at the end, you must call select() to populate the model with data."